# How to save selected time from TimePicker in HH:MM:SS format in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, format, timepicker

can any one please suggest how to save time picked from TimePicker in 05:30:55 format i.e HH:MM:SS format into sqlite database in android. I used Calender to save time. It is saving in 5:30 format.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code.

```
  int time=(picker.getCurrentMinute() * 60 + picker.getCurrentHour() * 60 * 60) * 1000;
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   String formatted = format.format(time);
```

And insert that formatted string to database.

Answer (score 0):

you need to supply every parameter in Date function.

```
 Date dt = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the raw time (the `long` used to back the Calendar instance) in your database and formatting it only whenever you need it for UI. It's much easier to do queries and other things (like compare dates) that way, and you can always do as Amit wrote any time you want.